# HTTP POST doesn't work on Internet Explorer 8 (after redirection)

Tags: asp.net, http, internet-explorer-8, https, http-post

I'm trying to redirect a domain to another site, without changing the first URL (**users should keep viewing** http://www.myurl.org since the new URL would be https://wwws.enterprisedomain.com).

I could do this, inserting a frame in the index.htm of the first domain (I know it's not the best practice, but it worked well for now):

```
<frame name="main" src="https://wwws.enterprisedomain.com">
```

The fact is that https://wwws.enterprisedomain.com has a login mechanism in ASP.NET. It's OK on Firefox and Chrome, but when we use Internet Explorer 8, it seems that **POST doesn't** work!

Comment: Why are you wanting to hide the fact the user is working securely?  - This is usually considered a bonus

Comment: Good question. Users are used with http://www.myurl.org. Changing the URL will affect severely.

Answer (score 0):

**Why hide the user is working securely?**

I think you're trying a solve a problem that doesn't exist, [take a look at this excellent library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx) which will direct users to the correct protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) regardless of what they type in. So a user who is used to going to http://myurl.org will automatically be directed to https://myurl.org without them doing a thing.

Forget the frame idea.

Comment: Thanks, but actually, the problem is that the HTTP POST doesnt works on IE 8. I mean its something related to doing POST on frames only in IE 8. I could change the frame idea, but users should keep viewing http://www.myurl.org

Comment: I suspect it's because he's trying to rebrand a third-party service for his own domain and it's not the secure bit that's the problem it's hiding the in-frame URL. Erup, if you host the frame to https://www.enterprisedomain.com/ in a secure page at https://myurl.org does that work - do you need a secure version of your container?